# Been away for awhile, credentials/badges seem gone. Can I relink to past posts, as some have relevance to questions I can answer?

Tags: support, user-accounts

Been awhile, I should have some old posts up here, can't seem to find them.

Comment: It seems you need to [merge your accounts](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: What do you mean by "relink to old posts"? Can you explain what you need, or rephrase your request?

Comment: Sure, I used to hang around on stack if I was stuck late at work. Had a proper rating, badges, etc. Moved across the country. Busy for awhile. Came back and looks like I'm starting anew, there's only so much time in the day. Same email, etc. Merge shouldn't be necessary. Any pointers

Comment: So you had an account? What keeps you from logging into it?

Comment: If you remember you previous user name, you should be able to find yourself by searching [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all).

Comment: I don't remember my handle, use to keep a cheatsheet nearby. Tried using my way old uni account. Got back in but history is gone.

Comment: So you logged in (not made a new acc) with your old credentials and your account was blank?

Comment: If you remember any questions you asked / answered, you can search on them and possibly find your ID that way.

Comment: Gallicfeyan, yeah, that's it exactly. Last post I remember getting some wicked upvotes on was a Mary Shelley Frankenstein post. My response was a link to Artur C. Clarke and Andrew Crosse.

Comment: [This is probably the answer you're talking about](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/84135/what-inspired-mary-shellys-frankenstein/96482#96482) and [this should then be your old user account](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/48675/alphaapple). You can then either [merge your accounts](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) or just stop using this one and try to log into your old one with the "forgotten password" functionality.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help, good to be back. Gimme a minute for a merge process.

Answer (score 7):

Per [your comment](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11070/been-away-for-awhile-credentials-badges-seem-gone-can-i-relink-to-past-posts/11071#comment34787_11070), [this is probably the answer you're talking about](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/84135/what-inspired-mary-shellys-frankenstein/96482#96482) and [this should then be your old user account](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/48675/alphaapple).

You can either [merge your accounts](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) or just stop using this one and try to log into your old one with the [account recovery](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/account-recovery) feature.